# Firestore data not getting stored in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store the user data in firestore, when I'm using the phone number as the document id it's getting stored perfectly but as soon as I changed it to uid it's not. And there were no exceptions been thrown at either. Also I checked if the uid is empty or not too and It's not empty either.

```
Future addUserToFirestore(String uid) async {
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid);

    final user = u.User(
        name: widget.fullName,
        email: widget.email,
        gender: widget.gender,
        nic: widget.nic,
        phoneNumber: widget.phone,
        bloodType: widget.bloodType,
        dateOfBirth: widget.dateOfBirth,
        address: widget.address,
        age: int.parse(widget.age));

    final json = user.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
```

When I use `.doc('+94${widget.phone}');` instead of `.doc(uid);` it works fine. But I want to use the uid as document id. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: when u create a user, set the uid as the documentId. u are currently using the phone number as the documentId thats why it works when u get a document by id using phone number

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method.
Hopefully, this will help.

```
   Future<void> storeUser () async {
     var instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
     await instance.collection("users").doc("uid").set({
       // add all of the user data here.
     });
   }
```

Else also try:

```
Future addUserToFirestore(String uid) async {
    // add await here as well

    final docUser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid);

    final user = u.User(
        name: widget.fullName,
        email: widget.email,
        gender: widget.gender,
        nic: widget.nic,
        phoneNumber: widget.phone,
        bloodType: widget.bloodType,
        dateOfBirth: widget.dateOfBirth,
        address: widget.address,
        age: int.parse(widget.age));

    final json = user.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
```

Comment: I think the issue was the String I passed, it worked when I changed it. Thanks for your help though It helped.